# Parsing and understanding the Git command line

Tags: git

Here is the description of one of the Git commands taken from here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch. To my understanding this site can be treated as official documentation. It that right?

I took `git branch` command as a sample. I hope all other commands follow the same rules. So, here is the sample:

```
(1) git branch
           [--color[=<when>] | --no-color] [--show-current]
           [-v [--abbrev=<n> | --no-abbrev]]
           [--column[=<options>] | --no-column] [--sort=<key>]
           [--merged [<commit>]] [--no-merged [<commit>]]
           [--contains [<commit>]] [--no-contains [<commit>]]
           [--points-at <object>] [--format=<format>]
           [(-r | --remotes) | (-a | --all)]
           [--list] [<pattern>…​]
(2) git branch
           [--track[=(direct|inherit)] | --no-track] [-f]
           [--recurse-submodules] <branchname> [<start-point>]
(3) git branch
           (--set-upstream-to=<upstream> | -u <upstream>) [<branchname>]
(4) git branch
           --unset-upstream [<branchname>]
(5) git branch
           (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>
(6) git branch
           (-c | -C) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>
(7) git branch
           (-d | -D) [-r] <branchname>…​
(8) git branch
           --edit-description [<branchname>]
```

So, I understand this description that:

1. The `git branch` command has 8 non-intersecting patterns. Exactly 8 patterns. Not 6 or 7.
2. Each pattern explicitly lists all keys and parameters that are applicable to this pattern.
3. Git makes decision on what pattern to apply based on the key(s) in the command line. I see that in the sample above all keys are present only in one pattern. There is no intersections.

Everything would be great, but all keys in the pattern 1 and pattern 2 are optional. This means that they can be all missing. How will Git make its decision in this case?

The command `git branch abcd1234-whatever`, is ambiguous between pattern 1 and pattern 2.

Am I missing something else here?

Comment: Pattern 2 requires a branch name, while pattern 1 does not

Comment: The `git-scm.com` site maintains web-formatted pages from the *most recent release* of Git. The official documentation for *your release* would be whatever came with it. Fortunately commands like `git branch` don't change very much very fast, so usually the most recent documentation is as good as somewhat older documentation and vice versa. To check your own Git version, run `git --version` or `git version` (both do the same thing, except in some very old Git versions that don't have both).

Comment: The website holds documentation for all versions, older versions can be selected on the page for each command using a dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all keys are optional for the second pattern. Notice that `<branchname>` is in angle brackets, not square brackets.

As a rule of thumb, the following lists branches:

```
git branch
```

The following creates a new branch:

```
git branch some_new_branch
```

The manual explicitly addresses the possible misinterpretation of `some_new_branch` as a search pattern for existing branches:

> Note that when providing a `<pattern>`, you must use `--list`; otherwise the command may be interpreted as branch creation.

So yes, there is an ambiguity to the general rule, but the authors chose to embrace it and provide an unambiguous workaround. Specifically, you have to explicitly use `--list` to indicate the optional positional argument to pattern 1 versus the mandatory unmarked one for pattern 2.

That being said, I wouldn't start with that part of the manual. While it's complete and accurate, it does not attempt to show you actual usage. The same official docs have an excellent tutorial section that will show you how to use git as a tool. The command manual is a great place to search for extended capabilities once you've learned the basics.

Check out the **Guides** section on https://git-scm.com/docs, e.g. https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial. As with many introductory materials written by the authors and maintainers of a project, these are excellent.

Comment: Second pattern does require branch name (although it is not a key in my terms). Although, the command `git branch abcd`, is still ambiguous between pattern 1 and pattern 2.

Comment: @Buran. See update

Comment: The tutorial available at  https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial is IMO not the best document to start. It is a little dated. The first chapters of the Pro Git book would be a better choice https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2. Just my 2 cents.